# Inline text overlays

Tags: beamer, overlays

I am trying to create a frame that contains an equation, where the relation operator changes on every slide. This is what I've got so far:

```
\begin{frame}{Tada!}
  \centering
  \huge
  Foo
  \onslide<1>{$>$}
  \onslide<2>{$\geqslant$}
  \onslide<3>{$\stackrel{\geqslant}{?}$}
  Bar
\end{frame}
```

This works, but the space for each symbol is "reserved", even when said symbol is invisible on that specific slide. How can I make overlays which are inline, in the body text, while occupying the same space?

Comment: it would be easier to test your example if it was a complete document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

- if you don't to reserve space, use `\only` instead of `\onslide`
- you need to protect the line endings with `%` otherwise they count as space

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Tada!}
  \centering
  \huge
  Foo
  \only<1>{$>$}%
  \only<2>{$\geqslant$}%
  \only<3>{$\stackrel{\geqslant}{?}$}
  Bar
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```